# Find string in file, append to the beginning and end of line containing string

Tags: python

I have my script looking at a text file that contains a lot of text on a lot of lines. I'm trying to get it so whenever the word "ERROR" is found, it appends to the beginning and end of the line containing "ERROR"

So far I have a variable that returns a list of all lines that contain "ERROR"

```
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    targets = [line for line in f if "ERROR" in line]
```

so if I print targets it will return a list of all of the lines that contain "ERROR".

targets[0] returns the first line etc.

I've also been able to apply the formatting:

```
for i in targets:
    format = '<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">' + i + '</span>'
    formatted_line = i.replace(i, format)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to have the script write a new file with all of the text including the formatting that was added to the start and end.

Just need a point in the right direction! Thanks

**EDIT: some clarification on the desired output:**

## original file:

log line of text here

log line of text here

error line of text here

log line of text here

error line of text here

log line of text here

## new file:

log line of text here

log line of text here

`<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">error line of text here</span>`

log line of text here

`<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">error line of text here</span>`

log line of text here

Comment: So you want to write `targets` to new file? I am little confused what is your desired output?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: So the new file that is created by the script will have the same text that was the input but with the changes applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open('output.txt', 'w') as OUT:
    for line in IN:
        if "ERROR" in line:
            f = '<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">' + line + '</span>'
            OUT.write(f + '\n')
        else:
            OUT.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: I'm assuming where you've put 'ad' it's meant to read 'as', right? for your second method I get ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'```

Comment: I got your first method to work but this writes a file that has the lines that have been edited. I'm trying to still include all of the other lines that weren't edited by the script

Comment: @samrb Try now. If you want all lines to be included you need to store those lines into another list also.

Comment: if you get a chance, check out a follow on question relating to this script
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920130/python-writing-html-anchor-points-dynamically-based-on-number-of-string-finds

Answer (score 0):

Just add a .split() function to the line in the if statement to convert it into an array rather than a string.

```
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    targets = [line for line in f if "ERROR" in line.split()]

print(targets)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think splitting the logic of reading and writing is more readable. And...readability is very important in coding.

I saved your text in a text file called `text.txt` and I saved the output in `new_text.txt`. I didn't know exactly what format you wanted for the result (mostly spacing), so you can play around with that to see what fits your needs.

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Get stored text
text_fp = Path.home().joinpath('Desktop','text.txt')

lines = []
with open(text_fp,'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if 'error' in line:
            line = '<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">{}</span>'.format(line)
        lines.append(line)

# New file name
new_text_fp = Path.home().joinpath('Desktop','new_text.txt')
with open(new_text_fp,'w') as fp:
    for line in lines:
        fp.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

Input data:

```
log line of text here
log line of text here
error line of text here
log line of text here
error line of text here
log line of text here
```

Result:

```
log line of text here

log line of text here

<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">error line of text here
</span>
log line of text here

<span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">error line of text here
</span>
log line of text here
```