# Python: writing HTML anchor points dynamically based on number of string finds

Tags: python, html

So the intention of my script is to take in a log file, highlight any lines that contain the word "ERROR", and then create and open a HTML file for displaying the log with the formatting applied.

I have finished that, works great. What I'm now trying to do is to have links written at the top of the page which link to anchor points wherever an ERROR line is found.

So far, I've been able to have the script print in HTML links at the top of the page which links to anchors like:

```
output.html#example0
output.html#example1
output.html#example2
output.html#example3
output.html#example4
output.html#example5
```

and so on, depending on how many "ERROR" words were found in the text.

The part I'm having trouble with now is getting them to link to the correct point on screen. So far, only the link to example5 works.

I'm sure this is because of a looping issue. It currently only works with the last iteration of the loop, which is why only example5 works.

But I can't seem to figure out where to place a new loop to have 0,1,2,3, and 4 to work.

```
infile = r"/Users/username/test-full-log.log"

with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.read()
    error_occurances = f.count("ERROR")

with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open('output.html', 'w') as OUT:
    for x in range(error_occurances):
        error_links = "example" + str(x)
        OUT.write('<a href=' + '"' + '#' + error_links + '"' '>' + error_links + '</a>' + "\t")
    OUT.write("<pre>")
    for line in IN:
        if "ERROR" in line:
            f = '<a id=' + '"' + error_links + '"' '></a><span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">' + line + '</span>'
            OUT.write(f + '\n')
        else:
            OUT.write(line + '\n')
    OUT.write("</pre")
```

If it makes it any clearer to understand, the log file that is being read looks a little like this

```
log line of text here
log line of text here
error line of text here
log line of text here
error line of text here
log line of text here
```

So in the above text it would highlight 2 lines (line 3 and line 5), as they contain the word "error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is because you are using last error link created by previous loop.
- For second loop where you are adding `<span>` tag you need to start count from zero again.
- try this code it should work.

```
infile = r"/Users/username/test-full-log.log"

with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.read()
    error_occurances = f.count("ERROR")

with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open('output.html', 'w') as OUT:
    for x in range(error_occurances):
        error_links = "example" + str(x)
        OUT.write('<a href=' + '"' + '#' + error_links + '"' '>' + error_links + '</a>' + "\t")
    OUT.write("<pre>")
    x = 0
    for line in IN:
        if "ERROR" in line:
            error_links = "example" + str(x)
            x+=1
            f = '<a id=' + '"' + error_links + '"' '></a><span style="background-color: #ff0000; color: #ffffff;">' + line + '</span>'
            OUT.write(f + '\n')
        else:
            OUT.write(line + '\n')
    OUT.write("</pre")
```

Comment: works perfectly. I'll look through the code more to try and fully understand it. By the way, if I wanted it to write Error 1 rather than Error 0 (so it counts from 1 onwards rather than 0) would I just change x = 0... to x = 1?